# Running Python Azure Functions on Windows 10 using VSCode

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to develop Azure Functions in Python on Windows 10 PC. Every time I try to debug it I get this error: "AttributeError: module 'azure.functions_worker' has no attribute 'start_async' "

I am running Python 3.6.8,
Azure Function Core Tools (2.7.1158)
And Function Run time: 2.0.12438.0
VSCode latest

Tried to remove and re-install the Azure CLI

Comment: Meant to say, please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the section [`Prerequisites`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#prerequisites) of the offical tutorial `Create an HTTP triggered function in Azure`, please downgrade your Python runtime from `3.8` to `3.6`. I'm sure that Azure Function Core Tools is not ready for supporting Python version higher than `3.6`.

As my case, I even can not install the function devkits when using Python 3.7 on my Windows 10. So I installed a new Python 3.6 runtime and change my PATH to enable it to fix my issue.

Comment: I have python 3.6.8 installed not 3.8.6. Sorry my fault. I tried all flavors of 3.6 (3.6.0, 3.6.6 and 3.6.8) but I still get the "AttributeError: module 'azure.functions_worker' has no attribute 'start_async' ".  I installed and run my python envs via Anaconda.

Comment: @DWorkie Could you update the post about more details for the steps you did?

Comment: Hi Peter, here are my steps:

Comment: Hi Peter, here are my steps: 
• I have Azure active subscription, 
• Installed Python 3.6.0 (and tried later all flavours of 3.6.x)
• Installed the Azure core tools and CLI
• Have the latest VsCode
• (I have prior installations of VS2019 and earlier
• And followed the instructions here to create azure python function
Unfortunately, I still the get the error I reported. Hope this helps, Peter and thanks.

Comment: I mean the instruction here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python

Comment: By the way, I am running on Windows 10 machine

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem on Win10 when I was using Python 3.6-32bit. Installing Python 3.6-**64bit** made the error go away, so it is worth giving that a try if you haven't already.

Comment: AnentArcana, indeed installing 64-bit version of Python 3.6.8 sorted it out. Meant to update this with that information, but you beat me to it. Thanks :)